# How to name and organize unit tests that test a method with multiple parameters?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic

Given this method that has to be tested:

```
// Search the given value using the provided search options
// Return true if the searchValue was found; false otherwise 
bool Search(string searchValue, bool useExactSearch, bool useIndexing)
```

I have 6 significant searchValues (one with ponctuation, one with accented characters, one with line breaks, etc) that I need to validate with each possible combination of the useExactSearch and useIndexing. This means 54 test cases.

How do you go about that? Do you really write 54 unit tests? If so, how do you name them? Do you write tests only for the most significant cases? Do you write a single unit tests that loops over a table of param values and expected results? If I do a single unit test, it's harder to find which case is broken when the Continuous Integration reports a failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using NUnit (.Net), you can do this:

```
[TestCase("John*",true, false, false)]
[TestCase("*user*",false, true, true)]
[TestCase(".",true, false, true)]
public void SearchTest(string param1, bool param2, bool param3, bool expectedResult)
{
    YourClass clazz = new YourClass();
    bool result = clazz.Search(param1, param2, param3);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
}
```

The NUnit Test Runner will execute this 3 times. And, as you can see [here](http://versasolution.blogspot.com/2010/08/testcaseattribute-friend-in-nunit.html), the report shows all test cases separated, which helps you identify who broke the build.
This is probably available on most xUnit frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

In his book The Art of Unit Testing Roy Osherove recommends using this naming convention:

```
MethodUnderTest_ConditionUnderTest_ExpectedBehaviour()
```

Which seems reasonable. As to how to do multiple tests of the same function with different params, I think individual tests will make it clearer what went wrong, and you can used refactoring to minimise the duplication between the tests.

On a side note, it's not language agnostic, but NUnit allows for parameterised tests, so other unit testing frameworks might do this too. That's a nice halfway house between 'one single difficult to understand the reason for failures' test and 54 'almost identical, with loads of duplication' tests.

Comment: I'm not impressed with that convention. If we can test it, it must be deterministic. That means the expected behaviour is a entirely determined by the method under test and the condition under test, so the third part of the name is redundant. Secondly, if your design changes, the expected behaviour might change, but you might well still want to test that method for that condition.

Comment: @Raedwald: Yes, it should be completely deterministic, but if you come back to a test you wrote a year ago, it's nice to have the explanation for what you were expecting spelled out for you. As for your second point, if the expected behaviour changes, the test logic will change, so you can rename it at that point.

Comment: "it's nice to have the explanation for what you were expecting spelled out for you" that should all be in the assertion messages.

Comment: "you can rename it at that point": but why add that pointless effort? If teh expected behaviour is not part of the name, no such renaming is necessary.

Comment: In general I also use the "3 parts naming style", for example I like a test named Seach_WhenSearchingPartialWordsWithIndexingTurnedOn_NoResultsAreFound. But when you have 54 cases for a single method, the test names become rather long and hard to understand.

Comment: I prefer ShouldNotFindAnyResultsWhenSearchingPartialWordsWithIndexingTurnedOn. When you change the Method name from `Search` to `AdvancedSearch`, will you remember to change this test's name?

Comment: @Raedwald:  Yes that is in the assertion messages, but a good reason to put it in the method name is so that you can quickly understand what failed from your test runner summary.

Answer (score 0):

One should write tests at least for the significant test cases and the tests can be named in accordance to the test case like TestSeachForPunctuation, TestSeachForAccentedChars, TestSeachForLineBreaks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes splitting the parameterized test into positive and negative scenarios enables you to better name the "ConditionUnderTest" and "ExpectedBehaviour" part of the test method name if you use the pattern `MethodUnderTest_ConditionUnderTest_ExpectedBehaviour()`.

See the example given on https://freecontent.manning.com/making-better-unit-tests/

> As a compromise, you can extract the positive test case into its own test and benefit from the descriptive naming where it matters the most — in determining what differentiates valid and invalid delivery dates (listing 12).